# Supermicro X9DRL-iF doesn't boot anymore. Stuck on code B2

Tags: bios, supermicro

After fiddling with the BIOS settings, my Supermicro X9DRL-iF doesn't boot anymore. It doesn't post and get stuck after PXE with the code B2 and the Supermicro logo.

I've tried to clear the CMOS by removing the battery and shorting the JBT1 pads, without success.

I've tried booting a FreeDOS 1.0  USB stick made with my Mac and Unetbootin, I extracted the BIOS image on the stick and renamed it `SUPER.ROM`. I tried to boot starting up with CTRL-Home keys pressed, no luck either.

It just reads "sending OOB to BMC" at the bottom of the screen, but it still get stucked at the last Supermicro logo page with code B2...

In the readme file included in the BIOS update zip from Supermicro they are talking about moving the jumpers JPME1 and JPME2 to bypass SPI flash security and force the system to operate in the Manufacture Mode, but II think this is only related to update bios via network.

The ressources I could find:
The MB official manual, the readme from the BIOS zip, this tutorial:
[Supermicro X9DRL-iF hang up at POST screen in B2 status code with no any external device](https://superuser.com/questions/706795/supermicro-x9drl-if-hang-up-at-post-screen-in-b2-status-code-with-no-any-externa)

Comment: For the very unlikely case someone is interested, there's a small thread on the SuperMicro's board. https://webpr3.supermicro.com/SupportPortal/IssueMgt/TraceIssue?issue=703C8EB4285D00E777ECCD84BFD60167

Comment: Tumbleweed badge yes! But really, I can't use the small server I built and that makes me quite sad.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with Supermicro X9DAi, and I was able to wedge in boot process with pressing F11 key (for boot from the usb key and flash the BIOS) before trying to load the BIOS after I changed the video card. This error, as I understand it, is an error in accessing the periphery, it needs to be removed all peripherals in turn and keep trying boot with inserted usb driver (with new BIOS flash and AFUDOS).